# Solving A System Of Differential Eqautions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

So I'm a little unsure about how to solve this system of differential equations.  I missed the first five minutes of my instructor's lecture the day we went overt this, so I feel like I didn't quite get the whole picture.

Inasmuch, I feel like the chapter on Systems of Diff Eq's in Thomas' Calculus is not very helpful.

The question is:

"Find and classify (as stable or unstable) the equilibrium solutions of the following differential equations.  Use the Differential Equa option in Winplot to investigate stability."

$dx/dt= -0.01x + 0.02y \\
dy/dt= 0.02xy - 0.03y$

So this is what I started doing.

The equilibrium points are the points that satisfy the equation when each are set to $0$ correct?

So...

$1/100(-x+2y)=0 \\
y/100(2x-3)=0$

So then I believe we solve for one equation and substitute those values into the other.

Then for equation two to we would have $y=0, x=3/2$

Do we then substitute these values into equation 1?

What I have in my notes doesn't match what I thought I had to do, so I am a little confused.

I am running late for work, otherwise I would provide more information.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the first step correct:

We have that:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{100}(-x+2y)=0 $$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{y}{100}(2x-3)=0$$

Now we check the zeros:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{100}(-x+2y)=0,\ x = 2y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{y}{100}(2x-3)=0, \ y = 0,\ x =3/2$$

Now for each ODE, we check the values **above** and **below** each equilibrium point.

For $\frac{dx}{dt}$, when $x > 2y$, $\frac{dx}{dt} <0$. When $x < 2y$, $\frac{dx}{dt} >0$. Therefore the equilibrium point is **stable.**

For $\frac{dy}{dt}$, when $y > 0$, $\frac{dy}{dt} >0$. When $y < 0$, $\frac{dy}{dt} >0$. Therefore the equilibrium point is **unstable.**

Note that in each case, we are only analyzing the variable corresponding to the derivative that is taken. For the second equation, we are not worried about the value of $x$, only $y$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a big help!